# How to add a running total together?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a homework task to basically create a supermarket checkout program. It has to  ask the user how many items they are, they then put in the name and cost of the item. This bit I've worked out fine, however I'm having trouble adding the total together.

The final line of code doesn't add the prices together, it just lists them.

Code so far

```
print "Welcome to the checkout! How many items will you be purchasing?"
number = int (input ())

grocerylist = []
costs = []

for i in range(number):
    groceryitem = raw_input ("Please enter the name of product %s:" % (i+1))
    grocerylist.append(groceryitem)
    itemcost = raw_input ("How much does %s cost?" % groceryitem)
    costs.append(itemcost)

print ("The total cost of your items is " + str(costs))
```

This is for a homework task for an SKE I'm doing however I'm stumped for some reason!

The expected output is that at the end of the program, it will display a total costs of items added into the program with a £ sign.

Comment: Python 2 and python 3? Which is it?

Comment: @BlackThunder Python 2, given the presence of `raw_input` which i not defined anymore in python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through list to sum the total:

```
...
total = 0
for i in costs:
    total += int(i)
print ("The total cost of your items is " + str(total)) # remove brackets if it is python 2
```

Alternative (For python 3):

```
print("Welcome to the checkout! How many items will you be purchasing?")
number = int (input ())

grocerylist = []
costs = 0   # <<

for i in range(number):
    groceryitem = input ("Please enter the name of product %s:" % (i+1))
    grocerylist.append(groceryitem)
    itemcost = input ("How much does %s cost?" % groceryitem)
    costs += int(itemcost)   # <<
print ("The total cost of your items is " + str(costs))
```

Output:

> ```
> Welcome to the checkout! How many items will you be purchasing?
> 2
> Please enter the name of product 1:Item1
> How much does Item1 cost?5
> Please enter the name of product 2:Item2
> How much does Item2 cost?5
> The total cost of your items is 10
> ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this! Sorry that the question was a little vague in areas, first time posting here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your costs as `int` and sum them:

```
print("Welcome to the checkout! How many items will you be purchasing?")
number = int(input ())

grocerylist = []
costs = []

for i in range(number):
    groceryitem = input("Please enter the name of product %s:" % (i+1))
    grocerylist.append(groceryitem)
    itemcost = input("How much does %s cost?" % groceryitem)
    costs.append(int(itemcost))

print ("The total cost of your items is " + str(sum(costs)))
```

There also seems to be a problem with `raw_input`. I changed it to `input`.

Comment: The "problem" with `raw_input` is, it doesn't exist in python 3 (it was renamed to input)

Comment: Also, minor suggestion for improvement: Use actual string formatting instead of `"..."+str(...)` (The OP didn't have it in his code, but that doesn't mean it can't be improved ;) )